# Javascript clear

Tags: javascript

Is there a Javascript Clear function for a dropdownlist per se?

ddlist.Clear(); or something of that sort?

Comment: What exactly do you expect clear() to do? Remove all options from the list?

Comment: I was told there is a ddlist.clear where it would clear all values in whatever ddlist you are referencing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "clear the values" you mean remove all the dropdown `<option>` elements, the quickest and most concise way is:

```
ddlist.options.length = 0
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend checking out jQuery, it has some functionality similar to what you're looking for and can help javascript development in general be easier and behave closer to the same on multiple browsers.

http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/empty

Answer (score 5):

no, there isn't.  but you could do so like this:

```
function clearDropDownList(ddl) {
    while (ddl.hasChildNodes()) {
        ddl.removeChild(ddl.lastChild);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the innerHTML to "", or remove all the option childs programmatically:

```
var element = document.getElementById("selectId");
element.innerHTML = "";
```

Or:

```
var element = document.getElementById("selectId");
while (element.firstChild) {
  element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For an array, you can just use

```
arr = [];
```

for  elements, etc, you'll need to use a framework or delete each element in a loop

Answer (score 0):

Short.

```
while (ddlist.options.length) 
     ddlist.options.remove(0);
```